# Meteor Session API call not behaving reactively?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am using Meteor to display data from the open weather api. While this works, the problem I am having is that it does not update reactively. This means that I end up refreshing the page to see the updated weather.

I believe the culprit to this is the fact that I am calling this via `onCreated.` The following below is my client code.

```
Template.weather.helpers({
  youweather: function(){
    return Session.get('youweather');
  }
});

Template.weather.onCreated(function(){
  Meteor.call('calltheweatherman', function(err, res){
    if (err){Session.set('youweather', {error: err});}
    else {Session.set('youweather', res); return res;}
  });
});
```

My server code is like so:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'calltheweatherman':function(){
    this.unblock();
    var apiUrl = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=NorthKorea&units=imperial&appid=myapikeygoaway';
    var response = Meteor.wrapAsync(apiCall)(apiUrl);
    return response;    
  }});

var apiCall = function (apiUrl, callback){
  try {
    var response = HTTP.get(apiUrl).data;
    callback(null, response);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      var errorCode = error.response.data.code;
      var errorMessage = error.response.data.message;
    } else {
      var errorCode = 500;
      var errorMessage = 'Cannot access the API';}
    var myError = new Meteor.Error(errorCode, errorMessage);
    callback(myError, null);}
}
```

As stated, while the code works as it should, it does not update whenever the weather data changes.

Comment: I wonder if `this.unblock();` is the culprit.

Comment: @dubvfan87 trying it now. Will see if that fixes it.

Comment: `unblock` has nothing to do with it. There is no reason to believe that this code would be reactive in first place. The data source is a REST endpoint, which isn't reactive. On top of that method calls aren't reactive either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These method call you make is not reactive. You can make it rerun at certain intervals using `setInterval` and get the updated weather data from the API.

```
Template.eo_layout.onCreated(function(){
  Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    Meteor.call('calltheweatherman', function(err, res){
    if (err){Session.set('youweather', {error: err});}
    else {Session.set('youweather', res); return res;}
   });
  }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: There is also a reactive method package on atmosphere

Answer (score 1):

1. Method calls are not a reactive data source.
2. HTTP GET requests are not a reactive data source either.

As an aside: why do you first wrap the synchronous HTTP.get function into an async function and then wrap that again with wrapAsync ti make it synchronous again?

You cannot make a REST endpoint a reactive data source without at least polling that endpoint.